# Problems with Tkinter "autocomplete" Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, autocomplete

I have been looking for a way to add autocompletion to a tkinter ttk.Entry widget. I also stumbled with a website that suggested [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942371/tkinter-autocomplete-widget-lowercase-bias). Reading RobB's answer, I was able to make it work properly regardless of case. But for the kind of usage I am looking for (adding a new item to a SQLite database while getting autocompletion from previous records), there is also something weird about pressing  key. The first version of the code I tried (from [this link](https://gist.github.com/ian-weisser/10013110), by Ian Weisser) would delete a character everytime the user pressed . And this version on StackOverflow had stripped the lines of code that catched the `<Backspace>, <Left>, <Right>, <Up>, <Down>` keystrokes, but I think that while typing, if the user presses left, the autocompletion should be suspended, deleting the selected text after the cursor position.

So, how can we change the code so that the user may enter text normally and go back a few characters to correct any misspelling, without deleting the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited the code, based on those two sources and, for me, I think this works better:

```
    def handle_keyrelease(self, event):
    """event handler for the keyrelease event on this widget"""
    if event.keysym == "BackSpace":
        if self.position < self.index(END): # delete the selection
            self.delete(self.position, END)
        else:
            #self.delete(self.index(INSERT), END) 
            self.position = self.index(END)
    if event.keysym == "Left":
        if self.position < self.index(END): # delete the selection
            self.delete(self.position, END)
        #else:
            #self.position = self.position-1 # delete one character
            #self.delete(self.position, END)
    if event.keysym == "Right":
        self.position = self.index(END) # go to end (no selection)
    if event.keysym == "Down":
        self.autocomplete(1) # cycle to next hit
    if event.keysym == "Up":
        self.autocomplete(-1) # cycle to previous hit
    # perform normal autocomplete if event is a single key or an umlaut
    if len(event.keysym) == 1:
        self.autocomplete()
```

Basically, it's Ian Weisser's version. I added an `if` clause to the "backspace" key part and I removed the above commented lines in order to allow the user to go back and correct some misspelling. Now if the user goes back and edits something, the rest of the previously entered text will be intact and the text only gets deleted if the user presses (deletes only the remaining autocompletion but leaves the rest intact) or backspace (deletes autocompletion and one character at a time, as expected). If the user mouse-clicks in the text, nothing is deleted.